# awk error with "[" and "]" delimiters

Tags: linux, shell, awk, ash

I have string looks likes this

```
string="xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz"
```

I want to extract the number between the `[ ]`. I used the following `awk` command

```
echo $string | awk -F'[]' '{print $2}'
```

But this `awk` command returns error:

```
awk: bad regex '[]': Unmatched [ or [^
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'
2
```

**Order of `]` before `[` inside character class is important here.**

This shall also work by double escaping `[` and `]` using alternation regex:

```
echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | awk -F '\\[|\\]' '{print $2}'
2
```

OR:

```
echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{print $2}'
2
```

Comment: +1 I'm surprised that the `][` are interpreted as part of one character class, rather than the whole thing being interpreted as two empty classes. Another option would be to use `']|\\['`.

Comment: @TomFenech I have seen it someplace in the `awk` manual that best way to get the brackets, is the `-F'[][]'`

Comment: Or with double quote: `awk -F "\\\[|\\\]" '{print $2}'` or `awk -F "[][]" '{print $2}'`

Comment: @TomFenech its specifically defined by awk language that if you want `]` in a bracket expression (it's not a character class) it must be the first character or be escaped `\]`. Other characters that have meaning for bracket expressions (e.g. `-` as used in a range like `0-9`) have similar requirements on position/escaping within the expression.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)\].*/\1/g'
```

With awk:

```
 echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[";RS="]"} {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`

```
echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | grep -oE '[0-9]'

2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic approach.  It will get any number out of a text file:

```
echo "xxxxx.yyyyy[2].zzzzz" | awk -F "[^0-9]*" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:" ")}'
2
```

---

Other example

```
cat file
"C 56","Home athletics center","LAC"
"D001","50M Run","50M"
"D003","10.505M Run","100M","42K"
```

```
awk -F "[^0-9.]*" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:" ")}' file
56
001 50 50
003 10.505 100 42
```